# Getting the OLE value from a String with a date. (VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net

My first question on StackOverflow. Hope it gets recieved okay. :)

So I have a form with 3 text boxes.

Date:
Format:
Output:

Lets say you write the date like this "05/07/1994"
The problem i have when converting a date like that, is the culture support.
Is 05 the month and is 07 the day? This varies from country to country.
I wanna be able to write it in the "format" textbox. Like this:

Date: 05/07/1994
Format:dd/mm/yyyy

```
    Dim strDate                 As String = String.Empty
    Dim strFormat               As String = String.Empty
    Dim strResult               As String = String.Empty
'I got the code to split the "strDate" by every "/" or every "." so i can isolate the days/months/years in a list.
```

How would you create the logic, so that it reads the "format" and then handles the date in the way that the user want it

Thanks in advance! Please tell me if i need to formulate it in a different way.

Comment: The only thing missing is a question. What are you having trouble with? Have you looked at [DateTime.ParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.7.2) ?

Comment: By default the date would be parsed based on the user's culture so this might not be an issue. If you want to make it configurable you can use DateTime.Parse or DateTime.ParseExact with a given culture.

Comment: If you use a `DateTimePicker` you don't need to worry about it. Use the `.Value` property to get a DateTime value. Once you get a DateTime type you can format it any way you want. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @Mary Thank you so much! That helped alot :D